# R: how to read dbf files?

Tags: r

I want to read my dbf files into R. But when I use `read.dbf` from `foreign` package, it produce error like this.

```
dbf <- read.dbf("D:/War/Data/my_files.dbf")
Error in read.dbf("D:/War/Data/my_files.dbf") : 
  unable to open DBF file
```

Is there any way to fix it? Or the problem is from the file instead?

Comment: Have you tried to open the file with a DBF file viewer? There are many free DBF read/convert apps on-line and if they also throw an error then it's the file's problem.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried to open it in DBF viewer, and I think nothing is wrong when I opened it

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not corrupt then the following should work:

```
install.packages("foreign")
library(foreign)

dbf <- read.dbf("D:/War/Data/my_files.dbf", as.is = F)
```

Tested on R version 4.2.1

Comment: How can I use read.dbf if I want to specify which encoding the dbf is saved with and whivh endcoding I want it to save as dataframe or csv file?